# Using a binary tree type

Tags: haskell, types, tree, binary-tree, instance

I have this type declaration, representing a binary tree:

```
data Bst a = Empty | Node (Bst a) a (Bst a)
```

As I'm new to Haskell, I can't figure how to use it. Could you show me how to initialize some of its instances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data declaration states that there are two ways to construct a Bst: with the `Empty` constructor or with the `Node` constructor.

```
-- An empty Bst
bst1 = Empty

-- A Bst containing a single value.
bst2 = Node Empty 42 Empty

-- A Bst containing 3 values, 2 at the root, 1 in the left child and 3 in the right child.
bst3 = Node (Node Empty 1 Empty) 2 (Node Empty 3 Empty)
```

Answer (score 3):

Single Int node:

```
    2

 Node Empty (2::Int) Empty
```

The tree:

```
    2
   / \
  1   3

Node (Node Empty 1 Empty) 2 (Node Empty 3 Empty) :: Bst Int


    2
   / \
  1   3
       \
        5

Node (Node Empty 1 Empty) 2 (Node Empty 3 (Node Empty 5 Empty)) :: Bst Int
```

Comment: Last example is incorrect, it should `Node (Node (Node Empty 3 Empty) 2 Empty) 1 (Node Empty 3 Empty)`

Comment: I think I was fixing as you were commenting.

Comment: Also (not that it's really important for the illustration) these aren't binary search trees, what `Bst` almost certainly stands for.

Answer (score 0):

I'll rewrite your declaration slightly, to use a more idiomatic order of arguments to `Node`:

```
data Bst a = Empty | Node a (Bst a) (Bst a)
```

`Empty` and `Node` are what Haskell calls *constructors*.  Constructors can be used two ways:

1. As functions to construct values of their type;
2. As patterns in the special pattern matching syntax to analyze and disassemble values of their type.

If we load your type into the `ghci` interpreter, we can use ghci's `:t` command to show the types of your constructors:

```
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
*Main> :t Empty
Empty :: Bst a
*Main> :t Node
Node :: a -> Bst a -> Bst a -> Bst a
*Main>
```

So `Empty` is a constant that has type `Bst a` for any `a`, while `Node` is a function that produces a `Bst a` given three arguments: an `a` and two `Bst a`.  So to construct a value of the type, you use one of the constructors, give it the required number of arguments (none in the case of `Empty`, three for `Node`), and of the correct type.

Let me stress this bit again: *you can use a constructor the same way you can use any expression of the same type as the constructor*.  So, for example, just like you can partially apply a function in Haskell (apply it to fewer arguments than it takes), you can partially apply a constructor: `Node "foo" Empty` has type `Bst String -> Bst String`.